# ROS Answers SE migration: UR10 project

Tags: ros, gazebo, 3dcamera, ur10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I need a structure for my project.

**The aim is that a 3D camera tells a UR10 the location of an object (coordinates), then it moves its arm to the object and performs a circular path around it. During this activity it uses another stereo camera which is installed at the end of its arm to scan the objectl to generate a more detailed 3D model. At first I have to get it running in Gazebo and then using a real UR10.**

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, ROS Indigo and Gazebo 2.
Up to now I managed it to run the UR10 in Gazebo and control it using the Joint Trajectory Controler plugin for rqt_gui.

Next Step:
I think I do need a motion planning package to tell the robot that it should move its arm from one position(x0,y0,z0) to the other (x1,y1,z1-> which is provided from a Kinect, but that is just gimmick if I have enough time)... Moreover it should of course prevent collision. What kind of package whould you recommend? Movit?
How would you structure this project? Could you tell me more about the details?

I read a lot of the basics of ROS, Gazebo and ros_control, but in this case I need practical knowledge...

Thank you in advance & kind regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249317/ur10-project/) by [HannesIII](https://answers.ros.org/users/28698/hannesiii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello HannesIII,

MoveIt! is a good package to use for these kinds of problems. To tell MoveIt! to plan and execute paths, you can talk to it using either the `move_group_interface` (C++) or the `moveit_commander` (python). It's probably a good idea to look at the [MoveIt! Tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/) to get a feel for what MoveIt! can do and how it works.

As for a structure of your project: You will want to launch a completely configured `move_group` for the UR10 (available in the `universal_robot` package) and you can then run a separate node (either C++ or Python) that interfaces with it. The tutorials will help you with figuring out what to write in your node.

Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1